# What is the preferred mechanism for reuse/encapsulation in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nesting

I'm just starting out in Ti*k*Z, and I'm noticing a lot of friction around the issues of encapsulation and reuse, so I figure I must be missing some best practices. I want to create a multi-panel figure for an academic article. It's going to contain several plots, diagrams, labels, etc. Ideally, I'd like to work on each element in it's own file, then combine elements into panels (each in their own files), and then finally create the figure in a top-level file.

There seem to be four main ways of doing encapsulation/reuse: `tikzpicture`s, pics, macros, and exporting to EPS/importing back. What are the pros and cons of these methods? Is there another method that I missed?

Comment: This is a good approach to LaTeX and TikZ! I generally use `\newcommand` to nest things; you can pass required or optional arguments to enable surprisingly flexible encapsulation/reuse, especially for graphical stuff like TikZ. If that's not flexible enough for you, there's also [the `xparse` package](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb31-1/tb97wright-xparse.pdf) and its commands `\DeclareDocumentCommand`, etc.

Comment: Do your figures interact with each other, or can they really be separate? If the latter is true, the best is to make them as separate as possible, I can provide some code later on (if nobody else does so).

Comment: IMHO the real encapsulation power of TiKZ comes from its key-value system (`pgfkeys`). Styles are a very powerful means to define interfaces and implementations that can be parameterized, inherited, extended and (partly) overwritten.

Comment: @yo': Some elements of the diagrams would ideally be shared and nested.

Comment: @Daniel: My understanding is that pics are syntactic sugar on top of the key-value system. So far, I've had some trouble with them. For instance, you cannot define an object using multiple layers and then use it in another picture without declaring the layers in larger picture. In that way, they are leaky interfaces. On the other hand, they are difficult to scale, especially when nesting.

Comment: You can put the `pic` definitions into a TikZ library so that you just need to load the library to use the `pic`s. I find this works well. It isn't clear to me what the problems are you describe. Without seeing an actual example, there's not much to say. I've not had difficulties scaling them. On the other hand, I don't really know what you mean about nesting. I just use the `pic`s defined in the library inside `tikzpicture`s wherever.

Comment: I didn't want to get into specific examples so much, but as you know, setting the scale parameter on a pic does not work unless you use "transform shape". The problem I ran into is that if you try to scale pic A, which includes pic B, setting the scale on pic A does not scale pic B.

Comment: I know no such thing. I've certainly used `scale` without `transform shape` perfectly successfully. There are also packages which rely on this functionality. But it depends how you do it and what you do it to, which we don't know because you haven't said. I've never tried to *nest* `pic`s, though. So all I can say is 'works for me': your code must be relevantly different from mine.

Comment: That's strange. Take a look at page 252 in the tikz manual

http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf